# Component @Input inheritance

Tags: angular, typescript

I have issues with inheritance in components, I am trying to implement a hierarchy of classes for in-house components and services.
I have several classes that provide common functionality for the actual components, the aim would be to have easier to manage code.

For example, I have an (in essence abstract) base class:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ic-base-alpha-locale-sensitive-input',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
export class BaseAlphaLocaleSensitiveInput extends BaseAlphaInput implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  charCase: TextCaseType;
  ....
}
```

Which i try to use in a descendant:

```
export class AlphabeticInputComponent extends BaseAlphaLocaleSensitiveInput 
implements OnInit {
  ...
}
```

with a template

```
<input ... [charCase]="caseConvert" #input="ngModel" ...>
```

And i'm getting an error:

*Can't bind to 'charCase' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ...  [ERROR ->][charCase]="caseConvert"*

> What is the proper way to inherit @Input bindings in descendant
>   classes?

or

> In general what is the best practice for implementing abstract classes
>   from which several component implementations can inherit common
>   methods, properties and bindings?

Comment: what version of angular are you using? Because this is relatively new functionality

Comment: use `<alphabetic-input-component ... [charCase]="caseConvert" #input="ngModel" ...></alphabetic-input-component>`  instead of `<input ...`

Comment: Can you show the `@Component` declaration you are using for `AlphabeticInputComponent`

Comment: I was using 4.0.0 - an upgrade is on the way to 4.2.2.
This is how the component is decorated:
`@Component({
    selector: 'ic-alphabetic-input',
    templateUrl: './alphabetic-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./alphabetic-input.component.scss'],
})`
I would like to avoid having to define the template several times - as far as i know it will be overwritten by the child class entirely.

Comment: @PierreDuc, _new functionality_ - which is?

Comment: @PierreDuc : i upgraded to 4.2.5, but still getting the same error, charCase isn't a property of input.

Comment: @Maxiumus since [2.3.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#230-rc0-2016-11-30) you've got decorator inheritance

Answer (score 3):

You should not use the `input` tag, but the selector you defined in your `@Component`:

```
<ic-alphabetic-input [charCase]="caseConvert" #input="ngModel"></ic-alphabetic-input>
```

Comment: Yes i see, thanks. Its weird that the same template worked before i separated them to separate modules.
As long as i just import the scripts with the base classes it worked - now i don't understand why.

Comment: Actually that charCase parameter was part of a directive (i dont know why it does not get the Input binding). It does not belong to the <input /> tag.